# If Else using Column in Table

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have table named `studentlogs`, and it has column status on it. When I finished inserting records on student logs, I want to use an `if .. else` statement. The status column can only have 3 values: `1`, `2` or `3`.

Now, I want to do the following after I insert the records:

```vb
if status="1" then
   CALL SENDSMS()
ENDif
if status="2" then
   msgbox("")
ENDif
if status="3" then
   msgbox("")
```

How can I do it when I am dealing with columns?

Answer (score -1):

To get the value of a row in a specific column, you can use parenthesis right after the row object and specify the `ColumnName` or `ColumnIndex` property to get the value.

Also, when there is more than one potential value, you can ue a `case` statement, instead of a lot of `ElseIf` statements.

#### MVCE Setup

```vb
'declare local variables
Dim dr As DataRow

'create table
Dim studentLogs As New DataTable("StudentLogs")

'add columns
With studentLogs
    .Columns.Add("Status", GetType(Integer))
    .Columns.Add("OtherCol1", GetType(String))
End With

'add values
With studentLogs
    dr = studentLogs.NewRow()
    dr("Status") = 1
    dr("OtherCol1") = "Joey"
    studentLogs.Rows.Add(dr)
End With
```

#### Check Column Value / Row Status

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In studentLogs.Rows
    Select Case row("Status")
        Case 1
            Call SENDSMS()
        Case 2
            MsgBox("2")
            Exit For
        Case 3
            MsgBox("3")
    End Select
Next
```